# Is there a Linux CLI Tool for extracting a Page Range to make smaller PDFs?

Tags: linux, pdf, command-line

Is there a cli tool for extracting sections of pdfs and making new smaller pdfs? I want to do something like this: pdftool  -s 4 -e 10 'thefile.pdf' "thenew.pdf', where -s and -e are start and end pages respectively.

Comment: I don't know if the GNU `pstools` package can handle your PDFs, but they contain such a tool for PostScript. Once upon a time, PDFs were a kind of PostScript; but maybe the formats have diverged.

Comment: The answers to this question are good but you might also want to check out [my answer over at askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/a/282453/81372). It's a GUI script based on ghostscript.

Comment: "Once upon a time, PDFs were a kind of PostScript; but maybe the formats have diverged" - just to avoid that people get the wrong impression: PDFs were *never* a kind of PostScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred method nowadays is the one Spencer tells in his answer (+1 for it!).

Other people prefer `pdftk`:

```
pdftk thefile.pdf cat 4-10 output pages_4-10_from_thefile.pdf
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ghostscript with pdfs](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.05/Use.htm#PDF).

```
gs -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=10 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile='thenew.pdf' 'thefile.pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/):

```
$ pdfjam input.pdf 4-10 -o output.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `qpdf` well in Fedora 24

```
qpdf infile.pdf --pages infile.pdf 1-5 -- outfile.pdf
```

[qpdf manual](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html)